# How do I shrink the size of the radial gradient in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradient

How do I shrink the size of the radial gradient in Flutter?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    gradient: const RadialGradient(
    colors: [
    const Color(0xff11cbd7),
    const Color(0xff000405)],
    ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just added `radius: 0.4,`